# Extract date from timestamp containing time zone in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data containing dates of the form

```
2020-12-14T18:58:10+01:00[Europe/Stockholm]
```

but I really only need the date `2020-12-14`.
So, I tried:

```
DATE(Timestamp) as LastUpdateDate
```

which returned `Error: Invalid time zone: +02:00[Europe/Stockholm]`

So, thinking that the problem came from the time zone, I tried this instead:

```
TIMESTAMP(FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d", PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y%m%d", Timestamp)))
```

which magically returned a new error, namely

`Error: Failed to parse input string "2021-10-04T09:24:20+02:00[Europe/Stockholm]"`

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just substring the date part from the string. Try one of these:

```
select left(Timestamp, 10)
select date(left(Timestamp, 10))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should clean your data first.

```
select date("2020-12-14T18:58:10+01:00") as LastUpdateDate
```

This will work as expected.

Any chance of cleaning your data before using it in a query? Actually I think that `+01:00[Europe/Stockholm]` is not supported as format.